# Animation element when scrolling with disabled page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to make a welcome screen on the site, which will gradually decrease with scrolling, but the page itself does not scroll at that moment. When the item has decreased to the desired value, the page scrolls as usual.
Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dpaLrk82/4/

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(".hello").css('height') != "100px") {
        $(window).scrollTop(0)
        $(".hello").css('height', '-=20px');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="hello">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">Content</div>
```

CSS

```
.hello {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #ccc;
}
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
}
```

But these are just sketches that work poorly, especially in mobile browsers.

It seems to me that I often saw this feature on the landing pages.

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of is to seperate the Welcome page from the page that appears afterward. Maybe you could have it fade out, then use JavaScript's history manipulation to redirect the user to the next page automatically. When that page is loaded, you could try a fade in effect.

Comment: Also maybe try putting all the contents inside a single parent element that takes up the whole page (100% width and height), and set that element's "overflow" property to hidden, and "position" to fixed. After the effect is done set the element's position to it's default.

Comment: @9259829 I want to make the element decrease in proportion to the scrolling, that is, not just hide it, but gradually reduce it. I tried to do this in several ways. tracing the scroll event as an example works on all devices, but it's impossible to fix the scroll so that nothing shakes. if I use the overflow hidden property, the scroll event will not be called because there will not be a scroll.

Comment: @9259829 more ideas: use mousewheel and touchmove events for the desktop and mobile device. But then on a desktop it is necessary to simulate scrolling, tracking mousewheel, with all additional problems such as scrolling several points at a time or scrolling in different directions. with touchmove, too many problems. when the position of the scroll is changed exactly, the entire page jumps and shakes. I'm in stupor. but I clearly remember that I saw this effect on the lending pages. perhaps there is a library for this.